# Windows Portable Devices (WPD) redistributable for Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, redistributable, wpd

i am trying to use the Windows Portable Device (WPD) API under Windows XP.

MSDN says that the Windows Portable Device API **is** [supported under Windows XP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388998%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The WPD Application Programming Interface is supported in Windows 7, Windows Vista, and Windows XP operating systems.

WPD objects are exposed as COM objects exported from `PortableDeviceApi.dll`.

Except that the class:

```
CLSID_PortableDeviceManager = "0af10cec-2ecd-4b92-9581-34f6ae0637f3"
```

is not registered under Windows XP (SP3, 32-bit, Professional):

[image]

and the **PortableDeviceApi.dll** is not present on Windows XP:

[image]

Which means there must be a **Windows Portable Devices** redistributable i can ship to my Windows XP customers.

**Question**: Where is the **Windows Portable Devices** redistributable so that i may ship it to my Windows XP customers?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Windows Media Format 11 SDK for XP here: http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/licensing/Licensing_Win_Apps_CustApp.aspx

This includes a redistributable package that you can include with your application for XP customers.

Comment: Looks like their links are broken. Both the **Windows XP** and **Windows Vista** versions of the **Windows Media Format 11 SDK** point to the same download. Neither will install on Windows 7 (where i can then get access to the redistributable for Windows XP)